# SQL Server : update a record containing URLs to remove querystrings

Tags: sql-server, string, url, dns

I am trying to come up with a way to update a table that contains website visits including both the domain and querystrings. Since I am unable to update the application that sends this data to our web service (and cannot update this either) the only option I can think of is to handle this update though an Agent job that is run several times a day.

I have always handled this process programmatically, and my current fix is to simply use substring. But the best option if possible would be to simply remove the querystrings so that only `http://domain.com/` remains.

Basically I know I need to count the characters of the full string, count the characters from left to the 3rd backslash (`http://something.com/`), and then remove all characters from the right - left string.

Does anyone have some ideas I can try, so far all my attempts have been embarrassing failures.

Comment: What if the URL is `http://something.com/foo.asp?id=1`? Do you want the result to be `http://something.com/` or `http://something.com/foo.asp`? A querystring is technically the `?` on so the title doesn't really match the description.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah I forgot to include the removal of the file and querystring, so only the domain name (and sub domains) were listed.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, rather than running a SQL Job for this you can write a trigger on the table that is fired on every update; of course if there are not heavy updates on that table. In the trigger you can get the domain part something like the example below:

```
declare @url varchar(max), @index int
set @url = 'http://myurl.com/?q1=dummy&q2=dummy2&q3=dummy3'

set @index = case 
                when patindex('%?%', @url) = 0 then LEN(@url) 
                else patindex('%?%', @url) 
             end
select LEFT(@url, @index - 1)
```

Comment: Oh the reason why the agent job was the best option is because the table is basically a logfile that is updated though the webservice, that computers just dump the data into with a code and code text, where code can be website, error,application, etc.  And to make a long story short because of many problems with a badly designed database I wanted to have an agent script run and would separate the different code types (websites, applications, etc).  So I figured I needed to run an update agent job anyways, why not clean up the garbage.

Comment: Oh, and I don't think your response would work because it sounds like it is a query for a specific URL correct? I might not have been clear with my post, but the table is fulled with thousands of different domains (domains & pages & querystrings).  Basically I wanted to clean out the data so I can do queries on the top domains visited at x location on y day.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a view, instead of constantly updating the data? There's no reason to have to constantly run a job to strip the extraneous information - then the queries against it are only right immediately after the job has run.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.example(URL NVARCHAR(2048));
GO

INSERT dbo.example(URL) 
           SELECT 'http://somesite.com/foo.asp?id=1'
 UNION ALL SELECT 'http://someothersite.com/';
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.view_example
AS
  SELECT URL, StrippedURL = LEFT(URL, pos+1) + 
    SUBSTRING(URL, pos+2, CHARINDEX('/', URL, pos+2)-pos-1)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT URL, CHARINDEX('//', URL) AS pos
      FROM dbo.example
  ) AS x;
GO

SELECT URL, StrippedURL FROM dbo.view_example;
```

Results:

```
URL                               StrippedURL
--------------------------------  -------------------------
http://somesite.com/foo.asp?id=1  http://somesite.com/
http://someothersite.com/         http://someothersite.com/
```

(Note the calculation currently assumes your URLs will always have a third `/`.)